# Removing subdomain from Google crawling

Tags: seo, search-engines, google-search

Our `example.com` and `example.com/blog` links to our web app at `app.example.com`. The issue is that `app.example.com` returns a 404 on an uncached load, but the correct page does load — it's a weird setup with our react app.

We see these errors in the Ahrefs site audit feature.

[image]

How can we still link to the web app URLs, but have Google's bot exclude those entirely to remove the 404 crawl errors?

It seems like we can add a disallow on the web apps `robots.txt` file, but I'm not confident this will remove the crawl errors for `example.com` + `example.com/blog` that we're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

As you said yourself, a robots.txt served at app.example.com/robots.txt is the right choice to prevent Google (and other bots) from crawling your app completely.

Any bot crawling exmaple.com (including /blog/ and any other directory) will still see the links to app.example.com but cannot crawl them. Most likely, a tool like ahrefs will show you some kind of error message. But that does not matter.

And a general word of advice: the errors ahrefs (or any other third-party tool) is reporting to you are not necessarily relevant for Google. The closest thing we have to understanding what Google sees as a problem is Google Search Console. In this case, ahrefs is reporting 404 errors that ahrefs bot is seeing - not 404 errors that Google bot is seeing.